# jQuery: Find left offset while inside $.proxy

Tags: jquery, proxy, offset

```
this.progress.click(function(e) { // works
    var seek = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / $(this).width();
    self_ref[index].seek(seek * self_ref[index].source.duration);
});

this.progress.click($.proxy(function(e) { // doesn't work
    var seek = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / $(this).width();
    this.seek(seek * this.source.duration);
}, this));
```

`this.offsetLeft` works in the first example but not in the second. I **need** `$.proxy`, so I can't get rid of it. I can't find a way to get `this.offsetLeft` to work once the context has been changed inside it's function.

PS: I can no longer go back to using `self_ref[index]` because of an extensions I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either keep a copy of `this` in the outer scope like Dennis says, or use `e.currentTarget` to get the DOM element that is handling the event.

```
this.progress.click($.proxy(function(e) { // doesn't work
    var seek = (e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft) / $(e.currentTarget).width();
    this.seek(seek * this.source.duration);
}, this));
```

in your first example (non proxied): `this == e.currentTarget`

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the first example refers to the element that was clicked.  In the second, you are using it both to refer to the element that was clicked, as well as the object you are proxying the function to.  You can modify the original, working example by renaming `this` when you create the handler and creating a closure:

```
var self = this;
this.progress.click(function(e) {
    var seek = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / $(this).width();
    self.seek(seek * self.source.duration);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: both other answers are obviously far way better that this one. Respect :-)

---

In the first *working* example, `this` is the **DOMElement** that was clicked: `this.progress`

In the second example, when using `$.proxy`, `this` refers to the *surrounding* context, not the `progress` element anymore.

**So within the *proxified* handler**, you should be using:

```
 this.progress.get(0).offsetLeft 
 // .get(0) is to obtain the DOMElement
 // and get access to the javascript property offsetLeft
```

instead of `this.offsetLeft`.

Comment: It's not working, I tried several combinations to get the left. `offsetLeft`, `offset().left`, `left`, `.css('offset').left`.

Comment: Use `this.progress.get(0).offsetLeft` to work on the DOMElement (like is `this` in the first example)